# Save New entries in database to the Zeroth position - android database sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Need help in sqlite database coding for Android. I want to add the new entry to the zeroth position. Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code**

public void clickDone(View v) {

```
    EditText editIsbn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editPub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    String stringIsbn = editIsbn.getText().toString();
    String stringName = editName.getText().toString();
    String stringPub = editPub.getText().toString();

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    long id;

    // segment start
    id = db.insertTitle(stringIsbn, stringName, stringPub);

    db.close();

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getTitle(14);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        DisplayTitle(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No title found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
    // segment end

}

public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c) {
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "ISBN: " + c.getString(1)
                    + "\n" + "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n"
                    + "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

All I want is to add the new entry to the zeroth position.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions for your question.
1) You can clear database and enter  new entry.
2) You can add a column with current time(or any other value) , and when querying add order by clause.

**P.S at the time of asking question, You should add "Why do you want to do it." may be some one can give you better way then you are thinking.**